# C : Access violation reading location 0x00000044

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I have a file with heading [what],[where],[who] and I put it into an array list.
I am trying to concatenate the bracket and the array of words together. like [ what ] but error will pop up.

" Exception thrown at 0x0F20EDD0 (ucrtbased.dll) in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044 "

```
char intent[255];
char inv[3][10] = { "what","where","who" };

//char stringCat = strncat(intent, inv[0],10);
snprintf(intent, sizeof(intent), "[%s]", inv[0]);
```

can I know why does this happen?

Comment: check compiler warnings. You have 3 different warning types at least: mixing up chars & char pointers, using string literals instead of char literals being the most prominent.

Comment: `strcat` needs *pointers* not characters. `intent[0]` isn't a pointer.

Comment: `intent[0] = "["` => `intent[0] = '['`

Comment: If your compiler didn't warn you about those mismatches, you need to get a better compiler.  You will never be able to learn C with the compiler you're using.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the codes above but it is still giving me the error.

Comment: You probably have a mistake elsewhere in the program

Answer (score 0):

intent[0] is a char, not a char *.  strcat will append to the end of the char * pointed to in the first argument, so you are getting an error.  Changing to strcat(intent, inv[0]) will fix this immediate problem, but the code will still be wrong.

You need the string to be nil-terminated, so you need intent[1] = '\0' prior to the strcat().

strcat also simply writes to the end of intent, so stringCat and totalCat are pointless variables--they simply point to intent.

You would also do better to use strncat() than strcat() to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: Sorry , so instead of intent[0] and intent[6] I just put intent? wont that be overwrite?

Comment: No, strcat() adds to the end of a string.  strcpy() writes to the memory you are pointing to, strcat finds the terminating '\0' and starts writing there.

Comment: Also, if it were me writing this, I'd do it all with a single snprintf() call: snprintf(intent, sizeof(intent), "[%s]", inv[0])

Comment: Hi, I have changed the codes above but it is still giving me the error.

Comment: You have changed the declaration of intent to a char.  It must be a char array.  And you don't need to assign it the '[' or ']' chars--the snprintf() is doing all that for you.

Comment: oh ok. I have  changed it, now there is no error . but it didnt print out anything. it should print out [what] right

Comment: No.  snprintf() prints to the string.  printf() prints to the console.  After the snprintf(), you have the intent variable that is an array of chars, containing "[what]" (ie., intent[0] == '[', intent[1] == 'w', ... intent[5] == ']', intent[6] == '\0', and everything after intent[6] is undefined).  If you want to now display that to the console, you can call printf("%s\n", intent);.  Alternatively, if your only goal is to display to the console, you can replace the snprintf() call with printf("[%s]", inv[0]).